# How to use C# Task libraries to download and process a sequence of data

Tags: c#, .net

I've been struggling with a design to maximize the parallelism of a task using C# and Task libraries. Although I have some idea of various parallel processing concepts (and also reading multiple StackOverflow questions on the topic), I am having a hard time trying to assemble everything in a coherent manner that will solve my problem.

My problem has these properties/rules:

- I would like to download a time-stamped series of data from a HTTP connection in "segments" across a number of http servers/connections.
- Depending on the specific HTTP service, it will provide each segment of data in a differing size. For example, on one connection it may provide an hourly segment for each request (eg. "http://server1/getdata?year=2020&month=1&day=1&hour=1"). On a different connection, it might provide the data in a monthly segment (eg. "http://server2/getdata?year=2020&month=1").  It is not possible to get hourly data from a monthly connection or vice versa.
- If any one server fails or is busy with more than x connections, I would like to retry on a different server.
- When a segment of data has been downloaded, it requires to be processed into a data-set result. As much as possible, this processing should be parallelized.
- When the chronological first segment in the series arrives, I would like to immediately start processing it and processing each subsequent segment in chronological order (i.e. I do not want to wait for the entire series to complete downloading before responding to the caller).

Below is one of my attempts to solve this.  For the sake of clarity, I have only included the stubs of some code.

```
public IEnumerable<object> RetrieveData(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
{
    // Break the period up into the smallest segments allowed.
    // In this case, we will create one segment for each hour between begin and end dates
    var segments = new DataSegments(begin, end, IntervalTypeEnum.Hourly);

    var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancelToken = cancelTokenSource.Token;

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    // Start a number of tasks which are responsible for downloading segments
    // until all segments are complete.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            // Keep downloading segments until there are none left.
            while (!segments.IsComplete && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Empty;

                // Gets a list of connections available for downloading data
                var connections = DataConnectionManager.GetConnectionQueue();

                // Cycle through all the available connections until we successfully download 
                // a chunk.
                Retry:
                    try
                    {
                        var connection = connections.Dequeue();

                        if (connection is MonthlyDataConnection)
                        {
                            List<Segment> list = segments.GetNext(SegmentType.Monthly);
                            DownloadAndProcessMonthlySegment(connection, chunk, cancelToken);
                        }
                        else if (connection is HourlyDataConnection)
                        {
                            List<Segment> list = segments.GetNext(SegmentType.Hourly);
                            foreach(var segment in list)
                            {
                                DownloadAndProcessHourlySegment(connection, segment, cancelToken);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                catch
                {
                    goto Retry;
                }
            }
        });

        task.Start();
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    foreach(var segment in segments)
    {
        segment.Wait(cancelToken);
        if (chunk.Data != null && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            yield return chunk.Data;
        }
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

void DownloadAndProcessMonthlySegment(connection, segment, cancelToken)
{
    // Download from http connection, throw exception if WebException.
    // Process data if http download successful
    // Mark all segments as complete/ready
}

void DownloadAndProcessHourlySegment(connection, segment, cancelToken)
{
    // Download from http connection, throw exception if WebException.
    // Process data if http download successful
    // Mark segment as complete/ready
}

public enum SegmentType
{
    NextAvailable,
    Hourly,
    Monthly
}

// Represents a series of data segments that need to be downloaded
// In this code example, it will have hourly segments that span the specified
// begin and end dates.
public class DataSegments: IEnumerable<DataSegment>
{
    // Returns a list of segments that haven't been downloaded yet.
    // Depending on the "SegmentType", it will return just one hourly segment or
    // an entire month of hourly segments (SegmentType.Hourly)
    public List<DataSegment> GetNext(SegmentType type = SegmentType.NextAvailable);
}

// Represents a segment of data that needs to be retrieved from the web
// and processed into "Data".
public class DataSegment
{
    DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    // The processed data-set result
    object Data { get; set; }
}
```

The code works by using a series of Tasks that operate like Threads and loop until a list of Segments are downloaded and processed. Depending on the connection type (monthly or hourly), it will download and process the data accordingly (while ensuring no other task attempts to download the same range of data).

Although the code does (mostly) work, I feel it isn't the most optimal or elegant solution. One short-coming, for example, would be that the tasks could be held waiting for HTTP requests when it could instead be processing data. Another is that the connection and error handling is not ideal. For example, there is no handling for the scenario where more than x connections have been established to a server.

Would someone have a better solution or ideas to improve on this code while properly maximizing parallelism?

**EDIT**:
As requested by @Enigmativity, below is a full console app example that can be compiled.

Limitations of the solution:

- The number of running tasks are hard-coded.
- Each task is designed more like a Thread with a continuous loop rather than a discrete operation.
- Processing of segments is not parallelized as much as it could be.
- No exception handling.

  ```
   class Program
    {
        static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connections.Instance.Enqueue(new Connection(IntervalTypeEnum.Hourly));
            Connections.Instance.Enqueue(new Connection(IntervalTypeEnum.Daily));

            var begin = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
            var end = new DateTime(2020, 1, 5);

            foreach (var download in Download(begin, end))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Final result: {download}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static IEnumerable<string> Download(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
        {
            var segments = new DataSegments(begin, end, IntervalTypeEnum.Hourly);

            var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancelToken = cancelTokenSource.Token;

            var taskList = new List<Task<object>>();

            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var task = new Task(() =>
                {
                    while (!segments.IsComplete && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Empty;
                        var connection = Connections.GetNextAvailable();

                        var list = segments.GetNext(connection.IntervalType);
                        foreach (var segment in list)
                        {
                            GetSegment(connection, segment, cancelToken);
                        }
                    }

                });

                task.Start();
                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            foreach (var segment in segments)
            {
                segment.Wait(cancelToken);
                if (segment.Data != null && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Yielding data: {segment.Data}");
                    yield return (string)segment.Data;
                }
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        }

        static void GetSegment(Connection conn, DataSegment segment, CancellationToken token)
        {
            conn.WaitOne();
            var result = conn.Download(segment.Begin, segment.End);
            segment.Data = result;
            ProcessSegment(segment, token);
            conn.Release();
        }

        static void ProcessSegment(DataSegment segment, CancellationToken token)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing segment data: {segment.Data}");
            for (DateTime d = segment.Begin; d < segment.End; d = d.AddHours(1))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {

                }
                // Doing stuff..
            }
            segment.Status = DownloadStatusEnum.Done;
        }
    }


    public class Connection
    {
        static Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        public IntervalTypeEnum IntervalType { get; set; }

        private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(2);

        public Connection(IntervalTypeEnum type)
        {
            IntervalType = type;
        }

        public void WaitOne()
        {
            semaphore.Wait();
        }

        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get
            {
                return semaphore.CurrentCount == 0;
            }
        }

        public string Download(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
        {
            var data = $"{begin.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm")} - {end.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm")}";

            Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {data}");
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000));
            return data;
        }

        public void Release()
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public class Connections : Queue<Connection>
    {
        private static Connections instance = null;

        public static Connections Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new Connections();
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public static Connection GetNextAvailable()
        {
            Connection retVal = null;
            foreach (var connection in Instance)
            {
                if (retVal == null) retVal = connection;
                if (!connection.IsBusy)
                {
                    retVal = connection;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }

            return retVal;
        }
    }

    public enum DownloadStatusEnum
    {
        NeedsProcessing,
        InProgress,
        Done
    }

    public class DataSegment
    {
        public EventHandler OnStatusUpdate;
        ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public DataSegment(DateTime begin, DateTime end)
        {
            Begin = begin;
            End = end;
            Status = DownloadStatusEnum.NeedsProcessing;
            Data = null;
        }

        public DateTime Begin { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        private DownloadStatusEnum _status = DownloadStatusEnum.NeedsProcessing;
        public DownloadStatusEnum Status
        {
            get
            {
                return _status;
            }

            set
            {
                _status = value;
                Update();
            }

        }

        public string Data { get; set; }

        void Update()
        {
            // If the task is finished, then trigger anyone waiting..
            if (Status == DownloadStatusEnum.Done) resetEvent.Set();

            this.OnStatusUpdate?.Invoke(this, null);
        }

        public void Wait(CancellationToken token)
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAny(
                new[] { token.WaitHandle, resetEvent });
        }
    }

    public enum ChunkType
    {
        NextAvailable,
        Monthly
    }

    public enum IntervalTypeEnum
    {
        Hourly = 0,
        Daily = 1,
    }


    public class DataSegments : IEnumerable<DataSegment>
    {
        protected List<DataSegment> chunkList = new List<DataSegment>();
        protected HashSet<DataSegment> unprocessedList = new HashSet<DataSegment>();
        protected HashSet<DataSegment> inProgressList = new HashSet<DataSegment>();
        protected HashSet<DataSegment> completedList = new HashSet<DataSegment>();

        public DataSegments(DateTime begin, DateTime end, IntervalTypeEnum intervalType)
        {
            BeginDate = begin;
            EndDate = end;
            IntervalType = intervalType;

            DateTime requestDate = BeginDate;
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(EndDate.Year, EndDate.Month, EndDate.Day, EndDate.Hour,
                EndDate.Minute, EndDate.Second);
            DateTime finalRequestDate = EndDate;

            DateTime beginPeriod = BeginDate;
            DateTime endPeriod = DateTime.MinValue;

            if (IntervalType == IntervalTypeEnum.Hourly)
            {
                beginPeriod = new DateTime(beginPeriod.Year, beginPeriod.Month, beginPeriod.Day, beginPeriod.Hour, 0, 0);
                endPeriod = beginPeriod.AddHours(1);

                requestDate = new DateTime(requestDate.Year, requestDate.Month, requestDate.Day, requestDate.Hour, 0, 0);
                finalRequestDate = endDate.AddHours(1);
            }
            else if (IntervalType == IntervalTypeEnum.Daily)
            {
                beginPeriod = new DateTime(beginPeriod.Year, beginPeriod.Month, beginPeriod.Day, 0, 0, 0);
                endPeriod = beginPeriod.AddDays(1);

                requestDate = new DateTime(requestDate.Year, requestDate.Month, beginPeriod.Day, 0, 0, 0);
                // Calculate the last request date as the end day of the month
                finalRequestDate = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, beginPeriod.Day, 23, 0, 0);
            }

            while (endPeriod <= finalRequestDate)
            {
                var chunk = new DataSegment(beginPeriod < BeginDate ? BeginDate : beginPeriod, endPeriod > EndDate ? EndDate : endPeriod.AddTicks(-1));
                chunk.OnStatusUpdate += OnStatusUpdated;
                chunkList.Add(chunk);
                unprocessedList.Add(chunk);

                if (IntervalType == IntervalTypeEnum.Hourly)
                {
                    beginPeriod = beginPeriod.AddHours(1);
                    endPeriod = beginPeriod.AddHours(1);
                }
                else if (IntervalType == IntervalTypeEnum.Daily)
                {
                    beginPeriod = beginPeriod.AddMonths(1);
                    endPeriod = beginPeriod.AddMonths(1);
                }
            }
        }

        void OnStatusUpdated(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (sender is DataSegment)
            {
                var dc = (DataSegment)sender;
                if (dc.Status == DownloadStatusEnum.NeedsProcessing)
                {
                    lock (unprocessedList)
                    {
                        unprocessedList.Add(dc);
                        inProgressList.Remove(dc);
                        completedList.Remove(dc);
                    }
                }
                else if (dc.Status == DownloadStatusEnum.InProgress)
                {
                    lock (unprocessedList)
                    {
                        unprocessedList.Remove(dc);
                        inProgressList.Add(dc);
                        completedList.Remove(dc);
                    }
                }
                else if (dc.Status == DownloadStatusEnum.Done)
                {
                    lock (unprocessedList)
                    {
                        unprocessedList.Remove(dc);
                        inProgressList.Remove(dc);
                        completedList.Add(dc);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public IntervalTypeEnum IntervalType { get; set; }

        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public int UnprocessedCount
        {
            get
            {
                lock (chunkList)
                {
                    return unprocessedList.Count;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the 
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsComplete
        {
            get
            {
                return chunkList.Count == completedList.Count;
            }
        }

        public List<DataSegment> GetNext(IntervalTypeEnum type)
        {
            List<DataSegment> retVal = new List<DataSegment>();

            lock (unprocessedList)
            {
                DataSegment firstSegment = null;
                bool adding = false;
                int watermark = -1;

                foreach (var chunk in unprocessedList)
                {
                    //if (chunk.Status == DownloadStatusEnum.NeedsProcessing)
                    {
                        // Grab the first available chunk. If we don't find anything else that suits,
                        // we will just return this.
                        if (firstSegment == null) firstSegment = chunk;

                        if (type == IntervalTypeEnum.Hourly)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Reserving HOURLY segment for download");
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (type == IntervalTypeEnum.Daily)
                        {
                            // IF we are at the start of a month, then add these
                            // to our list until we progress to the next month.
                            // We take a note of the current month so we know when we have 
                            // moved to the next.
                            if (!adding)
                            {
                                adding = true;
                                watermark = chunk.Begin.Day;
                                retVal.Add(chunk);
                            }
                            else if (adding && chunk.Begin.Day != watermark)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Reserving DAILY segment for download");
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                retVal.Add(chunk);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // If we didn't find any matching chunk, return the first one.
                if (retVal.Count == 0 && firstSegment != null) retVal.Add(firstSegment);

            } // lock

            // Mark all the chunks as in progress
            foreach (var chunk in retVal)
            {
                chunk.Status = DownloadStatusEnum.InProgress;
            }
            return retVal;
        }


        public IEnumerator<DataSegment> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return chunkList.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
  ```

Comment: Firstly, i would be using the async version of your IO calls so that any one download isnt impacting your thread pool resources. You could probably make use of Dataflow or RX to pipline your concerns, but you will be in for a steep learning curve and although would be elegant solutions you would still need to solve the same problems you have identified, i would however suggest giving them a look through.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did look at Dataflow but wasn't clear how it would work in conjunction with the other task requirements. All the examples for Dataflow show discrete operations that returned a basic result and no conditional handling. In my case, I need to factor in fall-backs to alternate connections, different segment sizes, etc.  If I create a data pipeline, it's not clear to me how I would retry a different connection if one was unavailable or busy.

Comment: I would suggest using Rx. You'd almost get this into a one-liner. Can you please provide a [mcve] so that I can have a play with a solution? I'd need something that I can copy, paste, and compile in a Console App.

Comment: Everytime you use `goto` a fairy loses her wings. ;)

Comment: @MickyD Agree. I saw one lying there and that's why I created this post.

Comment: @Enigmativity I will try to get this for you, although I have already distilled as much as possible. I think the problem is unique because it contains several aspects to it: 1) A data pipeline  2) A connection limit and 3) A series of tasks. What would help you understand the problem better?  P.S. I unfortunately know nothiing about Rx but please note I am limited to only .NET v4.6.

Comment: Compilable code would help me more than anything. You've overdone it with your distillation. You just need to make the code compile and give me the input data (in compilable C# code) and I should be able to do the rest.

Comment: OK @Enigmativity, please give me some time to get back to you. Is is appropriate to post the full code here, though? It might be still rather large since it will need to include multiple classes which are only stubbed here. If I could make the code any more concise, I might have solved the problem   ;)

Comment: @Enigmativity Please see edit of my post that now includes full example source.

Comment: @SimpleGuy - Thanks. It compiles and runs. That makes things a lot easier. It's quite a lot of code so it might take a while to work through it. Please bear with me.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it @Enigmativity. I appreciate any different insight into potential solutions since I've been revolving around the same ideas for some time. I'm sure a fresh pair of eyes will help!